# get browser type in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, html5-video, user-agent

I need to load in different movie formats based on browser type.  Specifically if the user is using firefox then I need to load in a .ocv video.

I have tried using:

```
alert(navigator.appName);
```

but this always returns 'Netscape' in both chrome and firefox??

Is there a better alternative?

Cheers

Comment: I'm surprised that no one mentioned that all methods of browser detection are flaky at best. Your best bet is to see if the browser can support various video formats, and trying to load those.

Comment: I guess you didn't read my answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**STOP!!!** all proposed solutions are the reason the web is broken&breaking!

Don't assume a browser, based on the name you regexp out of the userAgent, can do something or not just because it sais its an IE, Firefox or Chrome. UserAgents can be and are faked! Do a feature detection either by hand or use something fullfeatured like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

What you want to do is provided via javascript. To check if the browser can do html5 video playback;

```
var canHtml5Video=function(){
    return !!document.createElement("video").canPlayType;
}
```

To check if the Browser can play a certain type (mp4, ogg), use the [canPlayType](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/av_met_canplaytype.asp) method of the audio/video element.

```
var elem=document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
if (elem.canPlayType("video/mp4")===""){
    //handle firefox and all browser that cant pay the mp4 royality fee
}
else{
    //handle mp4
}
```

Alternativ, you can just add multiple source elements to the video element. The Browser will chose what fits best.

```
<video>
    <source src="http://....mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://....ocv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

Comment: Feature detection is probably the way forward, but why do you think userAgent are faked? Why would anybody want to do this?

Comment: well, this happens because programmers did browser sniffing. So when I know my Browser supports something (but didn't 2Versions ago), I am pissed to be locked out. So I'll change the UserAgent to get access. This happens often in corporate intranets or systems like SAP, where they lockout all non-IE browsers so they only need to support the corporations default browser (IE6).

Answer (score 1):

Try 
    alert(navigator.userAgent);

For more information: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Comment: this is breaking the web! dont browser sniff, use feature detection!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use some like
[this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigator.userAgent` to get the browser details

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1) {
    // Inside firefox
}

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") > -1) {
    // Inside chrome
}

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") > -1) {
    // Inside IE
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for ie:

```
var ie = $.browser.msie;
```

for firefox:

```
var mozilla = $.browser.mozilla;
```

for chrome:

```
var chrome = $.browser.webkit && window.chrome;
```

for safari:

```
var safari = $.browser.webkit && !window.chrome;
```

Comment: this is breaking the web! dont browser sniff, use feature detection!

Comment: Where is the jQuery tag on this post?